# Prevent HoverZoom functionality on images in website

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hover

I am making a website with some images inside. I have Imagus (similar to HoverZoom) installed so that photos are automatically enlarged on hover. However, I do not want that to happen to my images.

It seems to work for some and not for others and I can't see why? Both pngs, etc.

Is there some kind of CSS or HTML I can put it that will stop the zoom?

EDIT: I've also noticed that the images that HoverZoom/Imagus enlarge, are also the images where the CSS :hover doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want any kind of actions happening when hovering over the images, you can add this, though I am not sure if it's exactly you want :

```
img {
   pointer-effects: none
}
```

Comment: I believe it's `pointer-events: none;`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to stop it.

If you just resize and save the image so that it is exactly the same size as you'll show it on the website, then HoverZoom doesn't do anything.